# Subtracting from a constructor that doesn't exist yet

Tags: java, class

I am trying to compare my wizard to do battle with another wizard. But the problem is the other wizard doesn't exist in the class file and only exists in the tester file. How do I access the wizard in my tester file to do battle with the one I have already made?

I have tried making a wizard in the class file, but I want the file to be able to do battle with their own wizard instead having a premade battle wizard already ready for them in the base tester. That's all I have so far, but I don't where to go from here. This is the entire code that I made in regards to the question. The arrow is the part where I am having problems.

````
    private String name = "Some_Wizard";
    private String level = "unknown";
    private String supplies = "branch";
    private int health = 100;
    private int galleons = 1000;
    private int status = 1;
    // starting Magician object
   public Magician(String name, String supplies){
    this.name = name;
    this.supplies = supplies;
   }
    // send name to toString when envoked
   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }
    // changes name when envoked
   public void setName(String nameUpdate){
      name = nameUpdate;
   }
    // sends name to toString when envoked
   public String getSupplies(){
      return supplies;
   }
    // changes name when envoked
   public void setSupplies(String suppliesUpdate){
      supplies = suppliesUpdate;
   }
    // gets the mage level
   public String getLevel(){
      return level;
   }
    // gets health
   public int getHealth(){
      return health;
   }
    // sets health
   public void setHealth(int hitPoints){
      health = hitPoints;
   }
    // gets the Galleons
   public int getGalleons(){
      return galleons;
   }
    // updates galleon amount
   public void setGalleons(int credits){
      galleons = credits;
   }
    // returns status
   public int getStatus(){
      return status;
   }
    // increases level of mage when envoked
   public boolean advanceLevel(){
   int i = 1;
      boolean upgrade = false;
      
      if (i > 0){
         upgrade = true;
         if (level.equals("unknown")){
            level = "apprentice";
         }
         else if(level.equals("apprentice")){
            level = "wizard";
         }
         else if(level.equals("wizard")){
            level = "shaman";
         }
         else if (level.equals("shaman")){
            level = "Level is maxed out";
         }
         
      }
         return upgrade;
      }
    // decreases the level of the wizard
   public boolean downgradeLevel(){
    int i = 1;
      boolean downgrade = false;
      
      if (i > 0){
         downgrade = true;
         if (level.equals("shaman")){
            level = "wizard";
         }
         else if(level.equals("wizard")){
            level = "apprentice";
         }
         else if(level.equals("apprentice")){
            level = "unknown";
         }
         else{
            level = "need to level up.";
         }
         
      }

      return downgrade;
   }
    // buys a wand
   public boolean buyProp(){
      boolean flag = false;
      String supply = supplies.toUpperCase(); 
      char ch = supplies.charAt(0);
      if (ch == 'S'){
      flag = true;
         galleons -= 300;
               }
      else if (ch == 'C'){
      flag = true;
         galleons -= 75;
               }
      else if (ch == 'B'){
      flag = true;
         galleons -= 100;
               }
      else if (ch == 'T'){
      flag = true;
         galleons -= 150;
               }
      else if (ch == 'S'){
      flag = true;
         galleons -= 300;
               }
      else if (ch == 'W'){
      flag = true;
         galleons -= 200;
               }
     else if( galleons <= 74){
      galleons += 1000;
     }

      return flag;
   }
    // now its time for battle <<<<<<<<<<<-----------Problem
   public void spellBind(){
   int dmg = 1;
      if ((dmg >= 1) && (health >= 1)){
         health -= 0.1 * health;
      }
   } <<<<<<<<<<<---------------- end of problem
   public boolean equals(){
      boolean equal = false;
    //      if (magician 
         return equal;
   }
}// end of class```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 problems here. I suggest you tackle them in order as it will probably make it easier to think about the second problem of "loading" a wizard from your test file.

Do you have a main class that handles the `Magician` entities/instances? How would you code 2 wizards starting a battle?

Think about your method signature. Perhaps it's useful for 2 wizards to be able to compare themselves to each other before they battle? Maybe if one has a really big hat or beard, or has lots of other wizard trophies stitched to his robe, the second one might not want to battle? I'd suggest looking at the `Comparable` interface documentation to think about this. This might help with your battle method signature too.

When you want to be able to load the stats for a wizard from a file, you need to think about some kind of serialization mechanism. Java has a built in class called Properties that you could use for this, or if you're familiar with JSON or YAML there are libraries you could use to help you. These are all text based so would be easy to maintain visually. You should do some reading about Java beans.

Finally, since it sounds like you're motivated by the fantasy gaming genre, you might consider looking at the code for one of the text based Multi User Dungeon (MUD) games. I used to code and play CircleMUD back in the day which was written in C, but I'm sure there are Java equivalents around now.

Comment: I am into the fantasy genre, but not enough to center my code around it. My mentor is though. They said the battle code in the tester would look something like cat.spellBind(dog), and then the dog would take damage from the spell. But in my mind, I don't see how that would be possible, seeing as the dog hasn't been created yet. Also I will try and find game equivalent code seeing as that could be a nice past time that can bolster my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently doesn't create any objects.

But from your question and comments I suspect that you need something like

```
Magician cat = new Magician("cat", "supply");
Magician dog = new Magician("dog", "othersupply");

cat.spellBind(dog);
dog.spellBind(cat);
```

For this to compile you need a method `spellBind(Magician)` in your `Magician` class:

```
public void spellBind(Magician opponent) {
    // do whatever is necessary to spellBind the opponent
    // i.e.
    // * spend seem of the current Magician's energy
    // * reduce the opponents health level
}
```

Note that it is not the responsability of this `spellBind()` method to create a new opponent - the opponent is provided by the calling code.